# Converting a complicated queryset from django to flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

As the title says I need to convert a queryset which counts the number of Services Waiters have after a certain time from the Django ORM to Flask. Here are my models:

```
class Waiter(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))

class Table(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_no = db.Column(db.String(128))
    
class Service(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Table.id'))
    waiter = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Waiter.id'))
    arrival = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now(mx))
    exit = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    tip = db.Column(db.Numeric(10,2))
```

And here's my django queryset:

```
Waiter.objects.select_related().annotate(num_Service=Count('service', filter=Q(service__exit__gt=time))).all()
```

EDIT:

Okay, so So far I think I've come up with something but I think something might be wrong with it:

```
waiters = Waiter.query(Waiter.id, \
func.count("*").filter(Service.exit>=datetime.datetime.now()) .\
label("service_count")).groupby(Waiter.id).subquery()
```

Does it look right? I need it to give me all the waiter Ids in one field and then the count for each waiter of the services they have that end after the moment the query is called.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you very much:)

Comment: Depending on the tools you are using with Flask, the same code can be run on Flask, too. What do you mean by converting this queryset? Do you want to write it with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. I can define the query's function further if it helps.

Comment: Good. Have you tried for it? Can you share your tries with us and your problems with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer that kinda does the same but with some differences. It doesn't return an annotated object but it returns a tupple of the object plus the annotation.

```
waiters = db.session.query(Waiter, func.count(Service.id).\
        filter(Service.exit>time)).\
            outerjoin(Service).group_by(Waiter).all()
```

It returns something like this:

```
[(<Waiter 1>, 0)]
```